# CAN BUS MESSAGES DESIGN SOFTWARE

Tags: pic, can, bus

I am currently designing with the PIC32 Micros and the 2 embedded CAN bus Controllers

As the CAN bus architecture from node to node can be very complex with CAN messages, nodes filters, masks, CAN channels RTR, etc. I was wondering if there is any software out there that can simplify the layout design.

At the moment I am using a drawing package to display the message layout for each node and drawing filters, masks, CAN message addresses etc.

This is very time consuming, and easy to add incorrect information

Just wondered if anyone knows of a custom designed program to aid me in this process

Thank you in advance for any help and info

Comment: Please edit your post and remove all-capitals and signature.

Answer (score 1):

In the automotive world, Vector's [CANdb++ Editor](https://vector.com/vi_candb_en.html) is quite popular, it supports the following processes:

- defining network nodes
- defining CAN signals (format: Intel/Motorola, scaling, offset, physical unit, ...)
- defining CAN messages (ID, DLC, ...)
- assigning signals to messages (message layout)
- ...

[image]